# Issue found: Invalid Data safety form child Audience

Tags: android, google-play-console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bZZG.png)My App is a Childern app of target age 3-12, i just use ADMOB to serve ads.
in Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types? i select "NO" and i recieve this mail . if anyone know how to correct this rejection kindly help.

Issue found: Invalid Data safety form

We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.

We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.

My App is a Childern app of target age 3-12, i just use ADMOB to serve ads.
in Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types? i select "NO" and i recieve this mail . if anyone know how to correct this rejection kindly help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.